# Black spots on Z-Buffer (Depth Pass)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, volumetrics

To begin, I'm using a MacBook Air 13" early 2005 model. I cannot render high-quality images with ease. I can only render on the iMacs my school has allowed me to use. If samples/quality is a part of my problem (Below), please let me know, I just really don't want to do the render if it is going to give the same results. Thanks.

Problem:
I have a scene where the camera is staring at leaves in trees. When I render, the images produce fine, but because I am wanting to use volumetrics and such, I have separated the scene into three layers.

1. Close branches
2. Tree canopy, volumetrics and a plane above creating a patchy effect in the light (Often used in ocean scenes to replicate light entering the water)
3. Clouds (Volumetric)

When I have rendered a small strip at 512 samples (CPU), I noticed the z-Buffer has black dots scattered throughout. This is on both layer 1 and 2 (Above). Layer 3 was unaffected.
Images:
[image]
[image]
Image of effects on final composition (Combined layers) -- Note white dots due to Z-Buffer:
[image]
[image]
FYI:
The Leaves are made from a black and white texture, which is randomly coloured and bump mapped. They are then used as particles on the tree.

Could this be due to overlapping planes?

EDIT:

The blender file as requested
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fV2ClOjU2D_PAN9cSSUXoWA90YnczlU2)

Thanks again,
BFB

Comment: Could the scene be provided please? Does not look like overlapping to me btw.